# How To Run Redux Example Todo List on NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express, reactjs, redux

i found example app on Redux documentation here http://rackt.org/redux/docs/basics/ExampleTodoList.html .

But have one question how to run it on nodejs server and preview the results on browser

Is beter if using expressjs as framework without using express generator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`package.json` there has all the packages requirements

use `npm install` to install all dependencies and then `npm start`

https://github.com/kweiberth/react-redux-todo-demo - This will come in handy for you - it isn't mine though.

Just copy the repo and get started.

Comment: i mean how create own node server, with react component on this link http://rackt.org/redux/docs/basics/ExampleTodoList.html